# ListView and ListItem behavior on onClick

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I have one custom listview with 3 textview and 5 imageview(star). First two textview are visible and third one is invisible. I am getting data from server and put into listview whatever how much.

**What i want**

If i click on any star(1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5) i want to get id from textview which is hidden. and star imageview change their images after clicked on it. Suppose i click on third star then 3 star will be rated and other will unrated.

**What i done**

Now i am able to get data from server and put it into listview but suppose i click star of any item then last item's star changes their images instead on clicked Item. and it's taking last id from hidden textview.

Here is my code.

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Student> {
StudentWrapper StudentWrapper = null;
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
Student student;
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

 public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,ArrayList<Student> studs)   {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, studs);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.students = studs;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View item = convertView;



    if (item == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        item = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        StudentWrapper = new StudentWrapper();
        StudentWrapper.menuname = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.title);
        StudentWrapper.hotelname = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.artist);   
        StudentWrapper.menuid = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvhotelid);   
        StudentWrapper.firstStar = (ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.hotelListFirstStar);
        StudentWrapper.secondStar = (ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.hotelListSecondStar);
        StudentWrapper.thirdStar = (ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.hotelListThirdStar);
        StudentWrapper.fourthStar = (ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.hotelListFourthStar);
        StudentWrapper.fifthStar = (ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.hotelListFifthStar);
        StudentWrapper.firstStar.setFocusable(false);
        StudentWrapper.secondStar.setFocusable(false);
        StudentWrapper.thirdStar.setFocusable(false);
        StudentWrapper.fourthStar.setFocusable(false);
        StudentWrapper.fifthStar.setFocusable(false);
        item.setTag(StudentWrapper);
    } else {
        StudentWrapper = (StudentWrapper) item.getTag();
    }

    student = students.get(position);
    StudentWrapper.menuname.setText(student.getMenuName());
    StudentWrapper.hotelname.setText(student.gethotenName());
    StudentWrapper.menuid.setText(String.valueOf(student.getMenuId()));

    StudentWrapper.fifthStar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Edit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            StudentWrapper.firstStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
            StudentWrapper.secondStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
            StudentWrapper.thirdStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
            StudentWrapper.fourthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
            StudentWrapper.fifthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
        }
    });

    StudentWrapper.secondStar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StudentWrapper.firstStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
            StudentWrapper.secondStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
            StudentWrapper.thirdStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
            StudentWrapper.fourthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
            StudentWrapper.fifthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Delete"+student.getMenuId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    StudentWrapper.firstStar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StudentWrapper.firstStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
            StudentWrapper.secondStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
            StudentWrapper.thirdStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
            StudentWrapper.fourthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
            StudentWrapper.fifthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Delete"+student.getMenuId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    StudentWrapper.fourthStar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                 StudentWrapper.firstStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
            StudentWrapper.secondStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
            StudentWrapper.thirdStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
            StudentWrapper.fourthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
            StudentWrapper.fifthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Delete"+student.getMenuId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    StudentWrapper.thirdStar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                   StudentWrapper.firstStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
            StudentWrapper.secondStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
            StudentWrapper.thirdStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.rated);
            StudentWrapper.fourthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
            StudentWrapper.fifthStar.setImageResource(R.drawable.unrated);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Delete"+student.getMenuId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return item;

}

static class StudentWrapper {
    TextView menuid;
    TextView menuname;
    TextView hotelname;
    ImageView firstStar;
    ImageView secondStar;
    ImageView thirdStar;
    ImageView fourthStar;
    ImageView fifthStar;
}
```

}

If i clicked on any star of any item then it reflecting on last item. I want to change imageview of that item and want to get text from textview of that item.
Please give me any hint or reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this in the Activity where the listview exist and not in the customadapter.

```
    adapterListview = new ListArrayAdapter(this, items);
    this.listview.setAdapter(adapterListview);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // global variable
            idItem = (int) id;

            switch (idItem) {

            case 0:
               // set your text and image for this item
            break;

            case 1:
               // set your text and image for this item

            break;

            case 2:
               // set your text and image for this item

            break;

            case 3:
               // set your text and image for this item

            break;
         }
       }
     });
```

id=0 is the first star, id=1 is the second star and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

May be ur ListView is taking the touch event and is transferring to each of the child.Because of this all the starts are highlighted